# How do I get access to the noaa rest api of the gfs data

Tags: weather, noaa, gfs

I am interested in getting the GFS forecast data for Europe which is available for free from the following website:
https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/global-forcast-system-gfs

According [this](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/support/access-data-service-api-user-documentation) site NOAA provides rest APIs for data access. I want to get access to the GFS 004 (0.5º) data (from [here](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/global-forcast-system-gfs), but how do I know the dataset name (which is described as dataset parameter)?

Or is there another way to get access to the GFS data over API?

Comment: did you manage to get access ?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: I answered your question then :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use other services that give you access to GFS data.

This one for example gives you access to GFS and more:

https://weacast.github.io/weacast-docs/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The GFS data is now freely available on Amazon AWS S3 under NOAA's Open Data Dissemination Program: https://registry.opendata.aws/noaa-gfs-bdp-pds/

You can see all the publicly available datasets here:
https://www.noaa.gov/nodd/datasets

You could write a simple API style query to pull the data down programmatically from AWS or use one of the libraries like boto3 (python).